# Spring AMQP Rabbit listener firing before "ApplicationReadyEvent"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

On Spring application start up I would like to look up a value in `Redis` and depending on that value I would like to turn off or leave on the message listeners I have.

It is also possible to not initialize these beans at all, but I cannot find a way to do either.

At the moment, I'm attempting to turn shutdown the containers using Spring's `ApplicationReadyEvent`:

```
@Component
public class ApplicationStartup implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

    private @Autowired @Qualifier("completedOrderContainer") SimpleMessageListenerContainer container;
    private @Autowired RedisManagerImpl redis;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
        if (!Boolean.valueOf(redis.isRabbitListenerActive())) container.shutdown();
    }

}
```

Container & AMQP beans are initialized as so:

```
    @Bean
    @Conditional(RabbitCondition.class)
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setAddresses(rabbitHost + ":" + rabbitPort);
        connectionFactory.setUsername(rabbitUsername);
        connectionFactory.setPassword(rabbitPassword);
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    @Conditional(RabbitCondition.class)
    Queue completedOrderQueue() {
        return new Queue(completedOrderQueueName, true);
    }

    @Bean
    @Conditional(RabbitCondition.class)
    TopicExchange completedOrderExchange() {
        return new TopicExchange(completedOrderExchangeName);
    }

    @Bean
    @Conditional(RabbitCondition.class)
    Binding binding(Queue completedOrderQueue, TopicExchange completedOrderExchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(completedOrderQueue).to(completedOrderExchange).with(completedOrderQueueName);
    }

    @Bean
    @Conditional(RabbitCondition.class)
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer completedOrderContainer(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, MessageListenerAdapter completedOrderListenerAdapter) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.setQueueNames(completedOrderQueueName);
        container.setMessageListener(completedOrderListenerAdapter);
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    @Conditional(RabbitCondition.class)
    MessageListenerAdapter completedOrderListenerAdapter(CompletedOrderMessageReceiver receiver) {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver, "completedOrder");
    }
```

Message listener:

```
@Component
public class CompletedOrderMessageReceiver {
    public void completedOrder(Object asyncTask) throws Exception {
        //impl
    }
}
```

The problem is, if I start up the application with a message already in queue, the message listener will pick up the message before `container.shutdown()` is executed.

Is there a way to achieve my goal? Even with a different approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `autoStartup` to `false` on the listener container(s). Then `start()` and `stop()` them as needed.

Comment: I too had a similar requirement and by setting  container.setAutoStartup(false), the container does not start the listener. I want to know how to start it again ? Because there is no method container.start().

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments on old answers. I don't know what you are talking about; all listener containers implement `SmartLifecycle` which declares the `start()` method. If you still don't understand, ask a new question showing the code and configuration and exactly what you mean.